# Is it bad to use "coefficient of determination" for recommendation?

Tags: recommender-system, metric

This is a general question about recommendation:

**Is it a bad idea to use "coefficient of determination"($R^2$) as metrics for recommendation?**

I am building a model of recommendation and wonder if it is a good idea to use "coefficient of determination" for evaluating models
As for pure regression I often use "coefficient of determination".
On the other hand, I cannot find "coefficient of determination" on recommendation Kaggle kernels or some benchmarks.

Comment: Do you mean $R^2?$ If might be helpful if you give the equation for what you mean.

Comment: Yes, I mean R square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, coefficient of determination ($R^2$) is not necessarily a good indicator for evaluating regression models. The equation of calculating R Squared is as below:

$R^2 = 1-\frac{RSS}{TSS}$

here RSS is residual sum of squares and TSS is total sum of squares. R squared only tells you **How much variability in $Y$ can the linear model explain**. See [this post](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/07/r-squared-predictive-capacity-statistical-adequacy.html) for a list of examples when R squared is not a useful indicator for model selection.

Back to the recommendation question: I'm not an expert but my intuition is R^2 cannot evaluate and rank the robustness of every single recommendation. See these kaggle notebooks below for a list of evaluation metrics.

- Cosine similarity, RMSE [link](https://www.kaggle.com/ibtesama/getting-started-with-a-movie-recommendation-system/notebook#Collaborative-Filtering)
- Similarity score and customized score [link](https://www.kaggle.com/fabiendaniel/film-recommendation-engine)